# SSD cloud hosting showing rotating disk device

Tags: debian, ssd, cloud, ovh

I have some application hosted on OVH public cloud supposed to be run on a SSD drive. When I'm connected on the instance through a terminal, `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` outputs `1`, meaning that the device under `/dev/sda/` is not of type SSD (cf. [How to know if a disk is an SSD or an HDD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65595/how-to-know-if-a-disk-is-an-ssd-or-an-hdd)).

Maybe I'm not looking at the right device ?

Comment: Per the accepted answer on the question you linked to, "It will probably not work if your disk is a logical device emulated by hardware (like a RAID controller)." That's gonna be quite common on cloud hosts.

Comment: All my KVM VMs show me that, even though their backing store is most definitely SSD. This is not reliable except for physical disks.

Comment: Does it mean that it is not really SSD but some hardware that mimic the behavior ?

Comment: The real question is, why are you trying to verify that the VM's backing store is SSD? The next step may be completely different depending on your real purpose.

Comment: @David Chances are it means there are *multiple* SSDs on the underlying server grouped together into an array. The less-likely option is that your host is lying; OVH is big enough this is probably not the case.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I didn't know cloud-based SSD drives could be implemented that way. Thanks.

Comment: @David Something to remember: "There is no cloud. It's just someone else's computer." Anything you can do on a local server is something a cloud host can implement on their end - to them, it's local, running in their datacenter.